# Converting a Sparksql Query to Dataframe transformations

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to re-write a sparksql query into a dataframe transformation using groupby and aggregate . Below is the original sparksql query .

```
 result = spark.sql(
         "select date, Full_Subcategory, Budget_Type, SUM(measure_value) AS planned_sales_inputs FROM lookups GROUP BY date, Budget_Type, Full_Subcategory")
```

Below is the Dataframe transformation that i am trying to do .

```
df_lookups.groupBy('Full_Subcategory','Budget_Type','date').agg(col('measure_value'),sum('measure_value')).show()
```

But i keep getting the below error .

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2475.agg.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`measure_value`' given input columns: [Full_Subcategory, Budget_Type, date];;
'Aggregate [Full_Subcategory#278, Budget_Type#279, date#413], [Full_Subcategory#278, Budget_Type#279, date#413, 'measure_value, sum('measure_value) AS sum(measure_value)#16168]
```

I am pretty sure this has something do with grouping by columns and those columns being present in the select clause .

Kindly help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you are doing `col('measure_value')` inside `agg` function, which does not make sense as for me, because you are not aggregating any value in such way.

Just remove `col('measure_value')` from `agg` and you will get right result.